# How do I control the whether a function will happen depending on the speed that a tableView is scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, scroll

I want an action to occur if a user scrolls down at any speed, or if a user scrolls up at a fast speed (or reaches the top of the view controller). I am using the following code below to sense any movement and implement the function where the "did move up" and "did move down" comments are, but I want to limit the did move up to occur only when scrolling fast or the user reached the top of the tableView. How do I do this?

```
// we set a variable to hold the contentOffSet before scroll view scrolls
var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0

// this delegate is called when the scrollView (i.e your UITableView) will start scrolling
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}

// while scrolling this delegate is being called so you may now check which direction your scrollView is being scrolled to
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        // did move up
        // I want this to only occur is the user is scrolling fast
    } else if self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        // did move down
    } else {
        // didn't move
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can store the time when `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` is called and then measure up the time difference against a certain amount of time in `scrollViewDidScroll`

```
var timeScrollingBegan: Date?

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // ...
    timeScrollingBegan = Date()
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        // Calculate time difference in milliseconds
        let timeDifference = Date().timeIntervalSince(timeScrollingBegan) * 1000
        let movementDifference = scrollView.contentOffset.y - lastContentOffset

        // If the movement difference is past a certain threshold
        // in a certain amount of time, then it is too fast. It will
        // take a bit of trial and error to determine the correct threshold
    }
    // ...
}

// You can probably use scrollViewDidEndDecelerating here instead
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    timeScrollingBegan = nil
}
```